# Generalized Linear Model in a Piecewise SEM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, structural-equation-modeling, piecewise-linear

I have applied a piecewise structural equation model to my data using generalised linear models. I have used the glm() R function along with psem in the "piecewiseSEM" R package.

It has worked, and I would Like to present the results, but because I am self taught I am full of self doubt and I would appreciate if someone could look at my code and output and see if I have made any glaring omissions or mistakes.

GLMs have been used because some of the data is not normally distributed and also because I expect/anticipate that some of the responses are non-linear.
I have used a piecewise SEM because I don't know whether some of my variables are predictors or responses, and theoretically they might go either way. Further, I sense it is a more mathematically sound approach than lots of linked regressions. I hope this sounds logical.

The models inside the SEM make use of 11 variables, none of which I transformed before inputting them. They are pH, three vegetation variables which are measured in %, one soil variable measured in %, and three further water quality variables with continuous and unbounded scales. The other 3 variables are species abundances, which are bounded proportions (but they are non-integers).

The GLMs with continuous variables as response variables use Gaussian family distributions whilst the GLMs with the species abudances use quasi-poisson families because they are counts but non-integers. Is this correct?

I have used the following code:

```
vegspec1 <- glm(specabund1 ~ ph + veg1 + soil1 + veg2*veg3, data = mydata,quasipoisson())
vegspec2 <- glm(specabund2 ~ veg1 + soil1, data = mydata,quasipoisson())
water1 <- glm(water1 ~ specabund1 + specabund2 + specabund3, data = mydata)
water2 <- glm(water2 ~ specabund2 + specabund3, data = mydata)
water3 <- glm(water3 ~ specabund2, data = mydata)
```

For the GLMs.
I have then combined this in a piecewise SEM:

```
sem.8 <- psem(vegspec1, vegspec2, water1, water2, water3)
summary(sem.8)
## summary - non-linearities detected in here
```

Because I have used GLMs in the SEM, this throws up the following error:

Error:
Non-linearities detected in the basis set where P-values are not symmetrical.
This can bias the outcome of the tests of directed separation.

```
Offending independence claims: 
 Saprotroph.Symbiotroph <- Symbiotroph *OR* Saprotroph.Symbiotroph -> Symbiotroph 
 
Option 1: Specify directionality using argument 'direction = c()' in 'summary'.
 
Option 2: Remove path from the basis set by specifying as a correlated error using '%~~%' in 'psem'.
 
Option 3 (recommended): Use argument 'conserve = TRUE' in 'summary' to compute both tests, and return the most conservative P-value.
```

I chose option 3, because my hypothesis does not support me in specifying a path. Am I right in doing this? I then run:

```
summary(sem.8, conserve=TRUE)
```

This gives me a functioning model with results I am very excited about. In the tests of directed seperation, I get a Fisher's C = 71.321 with P-value = 0.057 and on 54 degrees of freedom. This is a bit too close to a significant p value for me, and the model has returned some variables that are not independent. The AIC of this model 115.321.

I consequently run:

```
summary(update(sem.8, water2 %~~% water3, water1 %~~%water2, water1 %~~%w water3, specabund1 %~~% specabund3),standardize ="scale",conserve=TRUE)
```

This new model has a Fisher's C = 43.903 with P-value = 0.56 and on 46 degrees of freedom. The AIC is 87.903 so clearly a better model.

The rest I can confidently interpret: there are significant relationships identified, and at the end of the output the total R2 of each variable is listed, and consequently I can load this into a path diagram.

Can anybody answer my specific questions, and is there any obvious errors or problems that I have missed?

Comment: Did you come closer in finding a solution for estimating a ~generalized structural equation model?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'll note - as mentioned by Lefcheck [here](https://jslefche.github.io/sem_book/local-estimation.html#global-vs.-local-estimation), "A key point to be made is that the piecewise approach does not absolve the user of all assumptions associated with the statistical tests."

I interpret this as "each of your component GLMs should also be checked for goodness of fit." For each of your models (vegspec1, vegspec2, water1, water2, water3) I would recommend all of the standard checks: R-squared, delta AIC, overdispersion, residuals vs. fitted plot, using DHARMa to simulate residuals, etc. to make sure that they fit well.